# php time function

Tags: php

How can I get the current time,for example, in 10:45:47 am format using php?
can anyone help me by answering the above question?
Thanks to all.

Comment: Have you tried reading the PHP Manual on Date? http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 5):

```
date("h:i:s a")
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function like this:

```
echo date('h:i:s a');
```

See the formatting options for the `date` function to get more idea about it :)

Answer (score 0):

[`$time = time();`](http://php.net/time)
[`$date = date();`](http://php.net/date)